# need to view image in image viewer control in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

i read path of image file from Data Base then ineed to view it in image viewer but when i try to do this the image viewer was empty the path of the image that i stored in DB was that ("E:\MEdia Viewer Project") i don't know the steps i should do or what i can do .........

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="images.aspx.cs" Inherits="images" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">


        .style6
        {
            text-align: left;
            height: 61px;
        }
        .style7
        {
            height: 274px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .style8
        {
            text-align: center;
            height: 42px;
            font-family: "Arial Black";
            color: #000099;
        }
        .style9
        {
            height: 274px;
            text-align: left;
            width: 121px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">

        <table style="width: 100%; margin-left: 17px;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#CC6699" class="style6" colspan="2">
                    <br />
                    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        Font-Size="0.8em" PathSeparator=" : ">
                        <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <NodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#7C6F57" />
                        <PathSeparatorStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#5D7B9D" />
                        <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#5D7B9D" />
                    </asp:SiteMapPath>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#990099" class="style9">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="White" class="style7" valign="top">
                    Title:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    file path :<asp:TextBox ID="pathTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    Upload Date
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="282px" Width="393px" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#990099" class="style8" colspan="2" valign="middle">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this code is in load page

```
public partial class images : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlDataReader rdr=null;

         SqlConnection conn=null;

         try
         {

             string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];

             conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIMOFCIS-PC\\MYSQL;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI");

             SqlCommand cmd;
             conn.Open();

             cmd = new SqlCommand("select title,filepath,UploadDate from [Media] where ID=@id", conn);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
             // rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             // print the CustomerID of each record
             using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if (reader.Read()) // you don't need while loop
                 {
                     pathTextBox.Text = reader["filePath"].ToString();
                     DateTextBox.Text = reader["UploadDate"].ToString();
                     titleTextBox.Text = reader["title"].ToString();
                     Image1.ImageUrl = pathTextBox.Text + "\"+titleTextBox.Text+ "+".jpg";
                 }
             }
         }

        finally
        {
            // close the reader
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }
            // 5. Close the connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't store the path as the physical file path. You can't use that for image sources. Use a relative or absolute URL.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working the image that i need didn't appear just corrupted image appear

Comment: When you store as a relative URL, what is the result? What does your query return?

Comment: RETURN actual path of photo on my hard disk that's suppose to mean that when i run the program the image should appear but corrupted image keeps appearing

Comment: ... you can't use the actual path on your hard disk. You should store a relative URL like `/images/myPath/imageName.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's awhile since you posted this but for any others that find this!

Use a relative path for your images and then to find them relative to your aspx page you use the **Server.MapPath** and add the relative path to it.

e.g.
if (File.Exists(**Server.MapPath**("\Data\Competitions\CurrentSeason\" + round + "\Intermediate\Scores.xml")))